# How we define frequency in an image?

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals

How we define frequency in an image?

1. Does the repetition of a single gray level defines the frequency?(Example: can a black(single color/constant region) background image be called high frequency image?) I think it is not so.

Or

1. Does the frequency depends on number of changes in the gray levels in an image? If so Why? I couldn't able to relate the image frequency with the signal frequency where we say high frequency signal when the same cycle is repeated many times in a unit time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an image has large values at high frequency components then the data is changing rapidly on a short distance scale. e.g. a page of text

If the image has large low frequency components then the large scale features of the picture are more important. e.g. a single fairly simple object which occupies most of the image.

Thus low frequency correspond to slow varying information ( continuous surface)
high frequency correspond to quickly varying information ( eg. edges)

Answer (score 1):

The frequency of some image signal was traditionally given by a number of *cycles-per-millimeter* (or per other spatial unit). This is a historical unit of measurement that is related to the invention of photography and comparing lenses.

A cycle is also called a *pair of lines*. It is created by the alternance of a dark-then-white pattern. If the black and white lines have the same width, then you have a pure frequency. If the lines get thinner and thinner (as in most resolution test charts), then you have some chirp.

A constant region, whatever the color, is some continuous signal. High frequencies correspond to spatially fast changes in intensity: a pattern of dots or of thin zebras is high frequencies.

Since an image is a 2D signal, frequencies are defined with respect to their horizontal and vertical components (obviously, some diagonal pattern can be created by having non-continuous horizontal and vertical components).
You can find an example of resolution chart [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1951_USAF_resolution_test_chart).

If you want to experiment by yourself, you can try to generate various frequencies by creating fake 2D Fourier transforms with only 1 non-zero frequency and invert them.

Answer (score 0):

Another definition is from the basic mathematical theory provided by Mr. Fourier, where **any** (non-pathological) waveform or image can be represented by the composition of a bunch of sinusoids or sinusoidal patterns of different frequencies, even if there is **no** readily apparent repeating pattern or frequency of changes in the waveform or image.